# awk - Delimiter as combination of number and | (pipe) not working

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have an input file with some records as below,

***input.txt***

```
Record|111|aaa|aaa|11|1-bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
Record|11|1-aaa|aaa|111|bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
Record|111|aaa|aaa|11|1-bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
Record|111|aaa|aaa|111|bb|bb|11|1-cccc|cccc
Record|22|aaa|aaa|222|bb|bb|2222|cccc|cccc|11|1-dddd|dd
Record|333|aaa|aaa|11|1-bb|bb|333|cccc|cccc
Record|11|1-aaa|aaa|102|bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
```

i want to use a delimiter `|11|` in `awk` and get the second field, i tried the most common way as below,

***Command***

```
awk -F'|11|' '{print $2}' input.txt
```

***Output***

```
1|aaa|aaa|
|1-aaa|aaa|
1|aaa|aaa|
1|aaa|aaa|
|1-dddd|dd
|1-bb|bb|333|cccc|cccc
|1-aaa|aaa|102|bb|bb|
```

***Expected Output***

```
1-bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
1-aaa|aaa|111|bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
1-bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
1-cccc|cccc
1-dddd|dd
1-bb|bb|333|cccc|cccc
1-aaa|aaa|102|bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
```

Basically its not considering the last `|` of the delimiter `|11|`, instead it is taking a delimiter `|11`.

*i tried all below, none gave me the expected output,*

```
awk -F"|11|" '{print $2}' input.txt       # gives wrong output
awk -F\|11\| '{print $2}' input.txt       # gives Wrong output
awk -v FS='|11|' '{print $2}' input.txt   # gives Wrong output
```

Finally i had to write a `for` loop inside `awk` with delimiter as `|` to make it work, i would like to know why the simple solution doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Argument to `-F` is a regex.

```
awk -F "\\\|11\\\|" '{print $2}' file
```

or

```
awk -F '\\|11\\|' '{print $2}' file
```

or (Thanks to [EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton))

```
awk -F'[|]11[|]' '{print $2}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
1-bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
1-aaa|aaa|111|bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
1-bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
1-cccc|cccc
1-dddd|dd
1-bb|bb|333|cccc|cccc
1-aaa|aaa|102|bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
```

Comment: thanks it worked :). May i know why this require multiple escapes and why it is taking first | without escape  but not last ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer that question.

Comment: If argument to `-F` is only one character awk uses it as a string. Multiple characters used as regex.

Comment: @JithinScaria it required multiple escapes because with `-F'\\|11\\|` you're setting a Field Separator (FS) to a string and a FS is a regexp (with additional properties) so awk has to convert that string to a regexp before it uses it as such which requires 1 pass and uses up one of the escapes before you're left with the regexp you really want, `\|11\|`.

Comment: When you uses double quotes instead of single around a string in shell, you're exposing that string to the shell for interpretation so that adds yet another pass of parsing it before awk gets to it and so you need another escape, so you have the string `\\\|` parsed by shell into  the string `\\|` for awk which is finally parsed by awk into the regexp `\|`.

Comment: FWIW I'd use `-F'[|]11[|]` or `-F"[|]11[|]"` so you don't have to worry about how many escapes you need BUT I'd also always use single quotes instead of double around a string in shell anyway unless there's a specific need to have the shell parse it, e.g. to expand a shell variable.

Comment: Oh, and the reason you don't need to escape a `|` at the start of a regexp is that `|` is the alternation metacharacter - if it's at the start or end of the string then there's nothing for it to be expressing an "or" of and so it must be a literal character (or a bug!) and so doesn't need you to escape it to tell awk that it's literal. That functionality is undefined behavior by POSIX though so whether or not that's what happens is awk version dependent so YMMV.

Comment: Wow! .. @EdMorton Thank you for your awesome explanation.. very well understood.. and i am gonna use your solution `-F'[|]11[|]'` - its the best in all

Answer (score 0):

[Cyrus explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50773456/931027) why your delimiter does not work as expected (a combination of regular expression quoting issues).

With `sed`, removing everything up to and including the `|11|` on each line:

```
$ sed 's/.*|11|//' input.txt
1-bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
1-aaa|aaa|111|bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
1-bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
1-cccc|cccc
1-dddd|dd
1-bb|bb|333|cccc|cccc
1-aaa|aaa|102|bb|bb|1111|cccc|cccc
```

Comment: Thank for an alternative suggestion. .